# Upload files to Google Drive via HTTP request (C)

Tags: c, rest, http, google-drive-api, libcurl

I want to upload files to Google Drive using C programming.

I followed below instructions of [Google's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) & [libcurl example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html).

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE]
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]

[JPEG_DATA]
```

But I don't know what should I replace with the `[JPEG_DATA]`. Does it mean the file's name?

And for the `Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE]`, does it mean I should replace it with exact file size as shown by my computer?

Codes I wrote so far:

```
curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

struct curl_slist *header = NULL;

/* Content-Type: image/jpeg */
header = curl_slist_append(header, "Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```

Not sure what to put in the `[NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE]` below

```
/* Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE] */
header = curl_slist_append(header, "Content-Length:[NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE]");
```

```
/* Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN] */
char auth[200];
strcat(auth, "Authorization: Bearer ");
strcat(auth, access_token);

header = curl_slist_append(header, auth);

curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);

/* POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1 */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files");

curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "uploadType=media");

curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);

curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);

curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

/* Print response */
if(res != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
    curl_easy_strerror(res4));
}

else {
    printf("%s\n", chunk.memory);
}

curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

free(chunk.memory);
```

Thank you!

Comment: @ybungalobill hi, but if I want to upload a picture, how can I type the content of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[JPEG_DATA]` would be the exact content of the file, byte for byte. `[NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE]` is the size of the file, and coincidentally the number of bytes that are in `[JPEG_DATA]`.

You can see [post-callback.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html) to see how to add a payload to a POST request, and [httpput.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpput.html) to see how to read the data incrementally from a file.

Comment: hi, I can't quite understand how to type the exact content of a photo

Comment: @VanessaLeung: you don't "type" it, you read and send it through the callback as shown in the linked examples

Answer (score 0):

Treat the image as just regular bytes. Content-Type will tell the specific parser what the bytes attached in post body represent. After all its all ones and zeros. As long as http request response structure is met, it is not your responsibility to take care of chunking up the data and send it. The protocal is a contract with every field in header(before the skipped line), giving the meta data about your actual data. Once the necessary info(length, type, ...) is compliant, just read in the image as regular bytes and append to message. The rest is http(tcp/ip) problem.